# Get the last items from an xml array using xslt transformation

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have an xml with a list  of cars that look like this

```xml
  <Car>
    <color>red</color>
    <type>toyota</type>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <color>green</color>
    <type>mazda</type>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <color>yellow</color>
    <type>ford</type>
  </Car>
```

I'm currently getting all the cars information using xslt like this

```xml
<Cars>
  <xsl:for-each select="//list/record/car">
    <Car>
      <color>
        <xsl:value-of select="Color"/>
      </color>
      <type>
        <xsl:value-of select="Type"/>
      </type>
    </Car>
  </xsl:for-each>
</Cars>
```

What I want is to get only the items of the last car in the list using xslt so my new xml will have one car record  instead of 3  and look  like this:

```xml
<Car>
  <color>yellow</color>
  <type>ford</type>
</Car>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `last()` to get the last item. For example: `<xsl:for-each select="//list/record/car[last()]">`

If you're only fetching one item, you can remove the `xsl:for-each`. For example:

```
<Cars>
      <Car> 
        <color><xsl:value-of select="//list/record/car[last()]/Color"/></color>
        <type><xsl:value-of select="//list/record/car[last()]/Type"/></type>
      </Car>       
  </Cars>
```

Also depending on the structure of your XML you might be able to shorted it to:

```
<Cars>
      <Car> 
        <color><xsl:value-of select="//car[last()]/Color"/></color>
        <type><xsl:value-of select="//car[last()]/Type"/></type>
      </Car>       
  </Cars>
```

Update - As @michael.hor257k point out, the code can be simplified using `copy-of`. However it looks like the xpath has different casing to the output.

```
<Cars>
      <Car> 
          <xsl:copy-of select="//Car[last()]"/>
      </Car>       
  </Cars>
```

Note: your xml has `Cars` and your working xpath has `cars`. You might want to double check the casing is correct.*

Comment: Or simply: `<xsl:copy-of select="//Car[last()]"/>`.